# Accelerometer data, Z-axis gives wrong data?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I have an app for saving accelerometer and gyroscope and some other sensors data.
But accelerometer data from Z axis is wrong, so big... sometimes even X and Y data are not near 0 as they should be but near 2-3...
Z axis gives me data near 10 ...
Is there any error in code or ?
Any idea ?

data sample:

```
0|19:57:55:584|-0.08912659|-0.015655518|9.652756
1|19:57:55:653|-0.021209717|0.008834839|9.677216
2|19:57:55:704|-0.035308838|0.032958984|9.677216
3|19:57:55:753|-0.035308838|0.048065186|9.658646
4|19:57:55:855|-0.015686035|0.012008667|9.666275
5|19:57:55:906|-0.027709961|-0.006378174|9.6380005
6|19:57:55:955|-0.0539093|-0.04698181|9.582184
7|19:57:56:057|-0.05491638|-0.0053100586|9.64032
8|19:57:56:109|-0.0789032|0.020812988|9.684845
9|19:57:56:164|-0.16851807|-0.02734375|9.640045
10|19:57:56:258|-0.10827637|-0.035888672|9.696838
11|19:57:56:308|-0.09414673|-0.038009644|9.72084
12|19:57:56:358|-0.0569458|-0.030395508|9.680252
13|19:57:56:459|-0.06288147|-0.0049591064|9.663452
14|19:57:56:509|-0.047302246|-0.015167236|9.665237
15|19:57:56:563|-0.11026001|0.006500244|9.676056
```

Code:

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String s = time.format(new java.util.Date());
    try {
        writer.write(i+"|"+s+"|"+x+"|"+y+"|"+z+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, the accelerometer results from onSensorChanged are in units of m/sec^2, where the gravitational constant G is commonly known to be 9.81 m/sec^2. Note that this is different from iOS, where the accelerometer API returns data in units of G. So to convert your data to units of G, divide your data by 9.81 m/sec^2.

Note also that if your device is laying on a flat surface and not moving, then the z-axis will *always* have a force acting on it, namely gravity. It will be -9.81 or 9.81 depending on if your device is facing up or down.

Comment: Should I divide all axis or only Z ?

Thx

Comment: Divide all the axes if you want consistent values. Either stay in units of m/sec^2, or in units of G. Why would you want one axis to be in one unit, and other axes to be in another unit? By the way, select my answer if you like it.

Comment: thanks Can I do something like this ?

        float x1 = event.values[0];
        float y1 = event.values[1];
        float z1 = event.values[2];

        float x = (float) (x1/9.81);
        float y = (float) (y1/9.81);
        float z = (float) (z1/9.81);

Comment: Yes, that looks right. You can even do: `float x1 = event.values[0] / 9.81;`, etc.

Comment: SHouldn't it be -9.81 not /9.81 ?
Is it better to use linear acceleration ?

Comment: If your phone is on a table facing upwards, then your readings should say something like `x=0.0, y=0.0, z=-9.81`. Dividing by 9.81 will give you `x=0.0, y=0.0, z=-1.0`. Note that the readings will never be exactly 0.000 or 9.81 in the m/sec^2 units due to 2 reasons: (1) the hardware experiences jitter due to physical properties such as the temperature, and (2) the resting surface may not be 100% level.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I tried to use linear_acceleration and it Works perfectly...  It gives data without Gravity.. . I know it only Works in android api 9 and higher.  It is not problem .